# Convergent Series and Proofs

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am trying to get some clarity as to what exactly this is asking me?

Is this series convergent or divergent and prove:

$$s_n=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{n} & n\,\text{odd} \\ 0 & n\,\text{even} \end{cases}$$

I understand how to prove $1/n$ converges to $0$, but I don't know why it would matter if it is odd or even.

Comment: Showing $S_n \to 0$ is the same as showing $|S_n|\to 0.$ So how big can $|S_n|$ be here?

Comment: It seems you are asking about a *sequence* of values, not a *series* (a sum).

Comment: Yes, sorry.  I am asking about a sequence of values, but what exactly am I trying to prove?

Answer (score 2):

Note that $(1/k)$ for $k$ odd as a subsequence of $(1/n)$ is convergent with limit $0$. The constant sequence $0$ obviously converge to $0$. So in this case $(s_n)$ converges to $0$.

Comment: I get it.  That was the simple explanation I needed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_k a_k=\sum_k \dfrac{1}{2k+1}>\sum_k \dfrac{1}{2k+2}=\dfrac{1}{2}\sum \dfrac{1}{k+1}.$

If you mean sequence note that $0‎\leq‎ s_n<\dfrac{1}{n}$ thus use $0=\lim 0<\lim s_n<\lim\dfrac{1}{n}=0$

Answer (score 0):

You can use the definition of convergence: For $\epsilon >0$ you can pick a positive integer $N<\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ then it's easy to show $|s_n-0|<\epsilon$ whenever $n\geq N$